# How to use TextField from Django in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, django

I have a Django model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    charField = models.CharField(maxLength=200)
    textField = models.TextField()
```

and an HTML template with a JS function that displays `charField` and `textField` like this:

```
document.getElementById("someElement").innerHTML = "{{ myObject.charField }}";
document.getElementById("someOtherElement").innerHTML = "{{ myObject.textField }}";
```

The former works fine, but the latter doesn't. I assume the problem is the fact that it is a TextField because there is no other difference between the two. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a `<textarea>` you should use `.value`, so:

```
document.getElementById("someOtherElement").value = "{{ myObject.textField }}";
```

for `<div>`, you should ineed use `.innerHTML`.

Note that both are not a good idea since Django will HTML encode the values, and thus thus can result in `&quot;`, `&amp;`, etc. in the values. You should use the [**`|escapejs`** template filter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#escapejs):

```
document.getElementById("someElement").innerHTML = "{{ myObject.charField|escapejs }}";
document.getElementById("someOtherElement").innerHTML = "{{ myObject.textField|escapejs }}";
```

Comment: I did that but it still doesn't show anything. Any idea what could be the problem? It works when I put `{{ myObject.textField }}` directly in the element.

Comment: @Kristína: can you see anything on the browser console? Exactly what is the content that you render as output?

Comment: @Kristína: note that if you do this directly, the encoding is different, since for a html argument, it uses ampersand encoding, whereas for Javascript, you should JSON-encode it.

Comment: Sorry for a stupid question, I'm completely new to this. Should I type the javascript line into the console?

Comment: @Kristina: in firefox you can for example open de browser console with https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console/Opening_the_Web_Console  if you refresh the page, you can see errors that arise when rendering the page.

Comment: @Kristina: exactly what is rendered in the source code for the javascript value?

Comment: The element where the value should be shows just `<div id="elementId"></div>` when I call the function.

Comment: I tried changing `innerHTML` to `value` for the other element and it doesn't show anything either

Comment: @Kristína: what is the *value* you want to add in between, what is *rendered* by `"{{ myObject.textField|escapejs }}"`. If the `textField` is empty then of course it will not render anything.

Comment: It is not empty, `<div>{{ myObject.textField }}</div>` displays the text normally.

Comment: Could the fact that the text field contains line breaks cause any problems?

Comment: @Kristína: well as long as you do not share the rendered page source, you are the only one that can tell :).

Comment: Sorry for stupid questions again, by rendered page source you mean what I see in dev tools right? If so, there is nothing between the <div> tags.

Comment: @Kristína: no, you right click on the page and click on "View Page Source". Not the part between the `<div>` but the part in the JavaScript line.

Comment: Ah alright, the text is actually there. I changed value back to innerHTML and it works fine now, so the problem was probably the missing `escapejs`. Thanks for help!

Comment: @Kristína: yes, I was initially under the impression that it was a `<textarea>`, not a `<div>`. For a `<div>` it is indeed `innerHTML`.